# How to create nodes constrains in Neo4j automatically for 100 differents nodes?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to create the node constrains for 100 differents nodes.

I have a list of the nodes names and a list for the nodes variables, for example:

```
nodes = [skill1, skill2, skill3, ...]       variables = [s1, s2, s3, ...]
```

I would like to create all nodes contrains with a loop. I wrote this:

```
for node, var in zip(nodes, variables):
    try:
        with driver.session() as session:
            session.run('CREATE CONSTRAINT "+node+" ON ("+var+":"+node+") ASSERT "+var+".id IS UNIQUE;')
    except:
        print("Constrains already exists")
```

But It passes directly to the except statement and no contrains are created in Neo4j.

Someone has a solution to create different constrains in just one loop? Thank you!

Comment: You only need one var variable, `s` maybe, you don't need s1, s2, etc. The variable is only used for reference in the query, it isn't persisted.

Comment: Also check your query log for any errors. Alternately, print out what the cypher string will be and try running that in the Neo4j Browser to see what error it throws.

Comment: Thank you, the issue was the quotations marks, I was using double quotation marks (") inside the query while I used single (') quotations marks at the beginning and the end of the query. It has to be the same. Thank you for your answer ;)